# Is it possible to merge C# KeyCollections

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples

Having to work with some absolutely horrible code (not mine) which, sadly I don't have time to strip out and replace.

It creates a `Tuple<SortedDictionary<String, Dictionary<DateTime, MyObject>>, Dictionary<DateTime, MyObject>.KeyCollection>` (I know, don't ask). The values in the KeyCollection belong to the `Dictionary<DateTime, MyObject>` that's used inside the SortedDictionary, and this is piped down to a front end where the two are co-ordinated to create a date-based grid.

It's created like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, MyObject> dict = MyObjects.Select(i => i.Name)
    .Distinct()
    .ToDictionary(u => u, u => MyObjects.Where(i => i.MyObject.Name == u
        && i.Volume > i.Count.MinimumVolume)
    .ToDictionary(d => d.CreatedDate, d => d));

SortedDictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, MyObject>> da = new SortedDictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, MyObject>>(dict);
da.OrderBy(x => x.Key);

Dictionary<DateTime, MyObject>.KeyCollection dates;
dates = da.Values.First().Keys;

return Tuple.Create(da, dates);
```

However, it's come to light that there's a bug in this (unsurprisingly enough). On some occasions the DateTime range of da.Values.First().Keys isn't the same as the other Value collections, but as you see, the code that builds the Tuple ignores this, and just uses the first Date range, squashing the others.

The easiest way to fix this would be to somehow build up a dynamic KeyCollection of the various Dictionaries involved. But from my understanding of the object, this is going to be impossible because they items in KeyCollection are dynamic and "belong" to their original Dictionary.

Is this correct? And presuming it is, is there any other "quick" way out of this horrible, horrible mess?

Comment: From what i understand .. dates field contain DateTime from first tuple .. Which might not sync up with the Rest of the tuples ? And you want all the DateTime points ?

Comment: That's pretty much it. I have figured a way out of this - we're using WPF front end and I can change the LINQ to "get everything" then use a converter to strip away empty values. But I'd be interested in a cleaner or more efficient approach.